# How can we configure different server provider on a single domain. Ex. AWS, Digital Ocean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, digital-ocean

I had configured one instance server(AWS) with my domain(Namecheap domain provider) ex. **domain.com**.Of course, my server/website running perfectly in this case. Now I want to configure one droplets server(Digital Ocean) with my subdomain(Namecheap domain provider) for example **demo.domain.com**. But Now am too confused and had some doubts.

1. If I'll configure the DNS(For droplets) in the existing DNS(ec2 instance) then will it produce conflict in between?
2. If we can do point 1 easily then how can we configure without
3. If we can't do point 1, then what is the major difference between and why?
   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

point 1 . its not conflit because your dns configuration based on your domain Like domain.com dns configuration and demo.domain.com dns configuration is different you can ping any hosting provider based on your domain